# Bootstrap modal problem in Django project

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Im trying to use a bootstrap modal as part of my web application, but the pop up wont show when the button is pressed. I have copied all the code exactly as it is on the bootstrap site.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

I tried copying the code directly as it is from the bootstrap website but no joy.

Comment: @Nealium the question is tagged "Bootstrap 5", not 4.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. This includes debugging details, and the CSS and JS that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MrUpsidown. @OP, I believe you made the same mistake as me: You grabbed Bootstrap 4 stuff instead of Bootstrap 5

Edit all the `data-{attr}`'s to be: `data-bs-{attr}`

##### Final Block

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 5 Modal Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/